# Node is not getting installed and it is showing error

Tags: node.js

I was installing node by using the command on cmd npm install and I got following message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pezPt.png)

Please help me that how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Downvoting because text is posted as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm stands for `node package manager` which is used to `install external packages` or npm modules or libraries hosted on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). To get started with a Node JS Project you will need `index.js` and hit `npm init`, this will initialise your Node JS Project with auto genreated `package.json`.

Majorly Node JS, React JS or Angular contains following files:

- index.js/server.js(Entry File)
- package.json (modules/packages/libraries used in project and script can be written to run your project in different envs)
- node_modules (which is auto generated and contains all installed modules listed in package.json)

Answer (score 2):

According to your error message you don't have a package.json file so you need to initialize npm before installing node in your directory.
Initialize it with `npm init`.
[Npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Comment: Thanks Christopher Sabin yes the issue is resolved thank you

Answer (score 1):

Step 1- First install Node from **https://nodejs.org/en/download/**.

Step 2- Now go to your project file **cd project**.

Step 3- Type the command **npm init** in console.

Step 5- Now you can see **package.json** file in your project.

**Finish**- Now you can install any package by using **"npm install packageName"** command.